# C# Parallel.ForEach Shared variables syntax

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having issues getting the correct syntax for making sure my variables that are shared by multiple threads do not interfere with each other but stay local to the thread.

I am iterating through a datatable to define multiple variables.  Each thread would rely on its own set of the below variables.  Obviously this code overwrites the variables when each thread begins:

```
Parallel.ForEach(iterate.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
         //foreach (DataRow drow in iterate.Rows)
 {
    //Set Variables
    string insertDeliniator = "/"; //extra needed to build URI
    string insertInterplay = "interplay://"; //extra info needed to build URI

    InterplaySetup.InterplayEngineHostname = drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString();
    InterplaySetup.InterplayWatchFolder = insertInterplay + drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString() + insertDeliniator + drow["Interplay_Watch_Folder"].ToString();
    InterplaySetup.SafeForTranscodingFolder = insertInterplay + drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString() + insertDeliniator + drow["Interplay_Safe_Folder"].ToString();
    InterplaySetup.SafeForTranscodingSubmitURI = "interplay://Interplay/" + drow["Interplay_Safe_Folder"].ToString();
    InterplaySetup.TransferEngineHostname = drow["Transfer_Engine_Hostname"].ToString();
    InterplaySetup.TransferPlaybackDevice = drow["Transfer_Profile"].ToString();
    InterplaySetup.TranscodingProfile = drow["Transcoding_Profile"].ToString();
}
```

The variable values in the InterplaySetup class are then used later by other classes throughout the program for each thread.  Until the thread is complete, I have to keep the variable local to each thread.

Unfortunately I am having difficulty the examples of the syntax such as here on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703(v=vs.110).aspx) and am unable to apply it to my specific scenario.

I am wanting the threads to run in parallel - any help with the syntax would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a separate instance of `InterplaySetup` for each thread. It looks like that class is `static` so it is shared across all threads

Comment: You know that the threads disappear after the `Parallel.ForEach`. So when you say "are then used later by other classes throughout the program for each thread" that seems a bit wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the variable within the context of the thread.

```
Parallel.ForEach(iterate.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
{
    var interplaySetup = new InterplaySetup(); //Or copy from shared template
    interplaySetup.<> // access specific variable
}
```

Comment: I did original have that, but when I tried to get the variable value from there in another class, I would have to make a new InterplaySetup which would in turn clear the variable.  For example I had 'private string interplayWatchFolder; public string InterplayWatchFolder { get; set; }
        {
           get { return interplayWatchFolder; }
           set { interplayWatchFolder = value; }
        }'  But when I had to get the variable in another class, it would always clear because of making a new 'InterplaySetup()'.

Comment: @RyanJensen You only want to create a new one when you're creating them.  If  you need them outside the loop you'll have to store them in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an instance for each row and add to a list in order to access the results at a later stage.

```
var interplaySetupList = new List<InterplaySetup>();

Parallel.ForEach(iterate.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
{
  var interplaySetup = new InterplaySetup {
    InterplayEngineHostname = drow["Interplay_Engine_Hostname"].ToString(),
    ...
  };

  interplaySetupList.Add(interplaySetup);
}
```